# Xcode 8 and Swift 3 NSCalendar

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swift3

I implemented my watch project in Swift and now I am migrating to Swift 3 because of Xcode 8. I let Xcode 8 change the source code to Swift 3.  However, there are errors in the code and I can not figure it out.

```
let unitFlags: Calendar = [.hour, .firstWeekday, .monthSymbols, .year, .minute, .firstWeekday]

var calendar = NSCalendar.current
calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone(identifier: "UTC")!
let components = (calendar as NSCalendar).components(unitFlags, from: reservationDate)
```

Xcode gives error in these lines and I can not understand the problem.

> ERROR: Contextual type ' Calendar' cannot be used with array literal
>
> ERROR: Argument labels '(identifier:)' do not match any available
>   overloads
>
> ERROR: Cannot convert value of type 'Calendar' to expected argument
>   type 'NSCalendar.Unit'

Answer (score 36, accepted):

First of all, neither `NSCalendarUnit` in Swift 2 nor `Calendar.Component` in Swift 3 contain the components `firstWeekday` and `monthSymbols`.

In Swift 3 the equivalent of your code is

```
let unitFlags = Set<Calendar.Component>([.hour, .year, .minute])
var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")!
let components = calendar.dateComponents(unitFlags, from: reservationDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of unitFlags to Set