# Swift 3 Date Extension: Getting 'daysFrom' a date

Tags: swift3, nscalendar

In my old code I had a Date extension called "daysFrom" and I can't seem to migrate to Swift 3:

```
func daysFrom(_ date:Date) -> Int{
    //Swift 2: 
    //return Calendar.current.date(.firstWeekday, from: date, to: self, options: []).day

    //My Swift 3 attempt, doesn't work:
    return Calendar.current.date([.firstWeekday], from: date, to: self).day
}
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38920909/xcode-8-and-swift-3-nscalendar) Swift thread which says:

> ...neither NSCalendarUnit in Swift 2 nor Calendar.Component in Swift 3 contain the components firstWeekday...

So how do I replace this extension??

Comment: Your "Swift 2" version is not valid Swift 2 code, and firstWeekday is not a calendar component.

Comment: [Swift days between two NSDates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723431/swift-days-between-two-nsdates) has code for all Swift versions up to Swift 3: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38549470/1187415.

Comment: I have also updated the original question o Xcode 8 beta 6 http://stackoverflow.com/a/27184261/2303865

Comment: In response to @MartinR, at some point in the Xcode 8 betas, the migration assistant changed the old `weekComponent` to `firstWeekday` instead of `weekday` as it should have. Caused me more confusion than it should have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get days between two dates, use `dateComponents`:

```
extension Date {
    func days(from date: Date) -> Int {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: date, to: self).day!
    }
}
```

And then

```
let days = endDate.days(from: startDate)
```